# windows Application Database Connection c#

Tags: c#, sql, database, connection

Im facing problem with database connection on windows Application Database Connection c#... here is my connection ,,, PC2 is PCNAme

```
private static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=PC2\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=True"
);
```

when I run the form I get this unhandled exception on con.Open();

sqlException was unhandeled:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

hope some one can help Im trying to solve it for many hours but not working.

Comment: [Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Comment: Have you configured SQLExpress to accept remote connections? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

Comment: 1. have you installed sql server, 2. can you login using sqlcmd? 3. is  the sql server running

Comment: Probably an error locating the server or instance specified. Check it is actually there, and the SQL Browser is running, and the Firewall on both machines is allowing access to SQL Browser and SQl Server. Also may want to configure it to use static ports.

Answer (score 0):

Check this trouble shoot steps on MSDN:

[The SQL Server client cannot connect to the server MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1)

And much better if you separate your connection string to your ado.net sql connection.

```
private const string _thisConnectionString = "Data Source=PC2\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=SSPI";
```

Use the "Using" Statement ensure that you always close your Connection.

[Best Practices for Using ADO.NET MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx#adonetbest_topic4)

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_thisConnectionString))
        {
           SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText = "Your SQL Query STuff";

            conn.Open();

         }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
private static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
    "Data Source=PC2\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Database1;Integrated Security=True"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to SQL Server Configuration Management -> Click on SQL Server Services

Verify SQL Server and SQL Server browser both are running. you can see a Greed play button there. if it's not running right click on the service which shows Red, go to properties, Click Built in Account and Press Apply then OK, There try to start by right click.